# SCDF not picking up the latest application docker image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a SCDF running in opneshift. The batch application I want to register in SCDF is a docker image configured with latest tag. The docker image also has a webhook configured with corresponding git repo. So the docker image is always the latest.

But once I register the application, consecutive changes to my applications are not picked up by SCDF. Though the docker image was built (via webhook) once the code committed. How do I configure the SCDF to pick up the latest version or newly pushed version ? Right now the only option is to register a new application for the changes to take effect.

I tried using the FORCE option in app registration page. but it seems it'll work only if not being used already.

Is there any configuration I could add to deployment.yaml to get the latest version? Thanks.

Due to this I couldn't restart a failed job with a fixed version of code. As the Restart job always pointing to older version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image pull policy for the task as part of the deployer property when launching the task.

For more info, you can refer the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_image_pull_policy)

Comment: It's been set already in the scdf server-config.yaml. Is there anything else I need to set?

Comment: Not sure what you have in the server-config. But, typically what you set at the server config is applicable for the server container image not to the task application container image that gets deployed.